# Is it possible to create Google Drive Presentation via API?

Tags: google-drive-api

We are going to build some service using Google Apps Engine.
And I wonder if it's possible to create Presentation using API?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You just need to [insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) a file with the mimeType of `application/vnd.google-apps.presentation`. See [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/mime-types?hl=en) for other possible Google Docs file types.